# Overriding onChange behavior with React / Redux Forms

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm building a complex form in React and am trying to use Redux Forms as a helper tool.

The requirements of the project are that:

1. There will be values on the page that change depending on the
   input fields (like an excel spreadsheet)
2. There will be at least one field that functions both as an input
   field and a dependent field (it can be changed, but also changes
   when other fields are changed)
3. I want to control when the state changes.  By default, it will
   happen instantly when inputs change, but I'd rather have a delay
   like [this example](https://schier.co/blog/2014/12/08/wait-for-user-to-stop-typing-using-javascript.html).

The first function basically follows the tutorial of Redux Forms, I have that working.  However, the other two require modifying what happens when a field updates and I am having trouble figuring out how to do that.  I could imagine how to do this from scratch, but wanted to see if there was a way to use this library to keep things simpler.

My code is up on [GitHub](https://github.com/petervkay/roiCalculator/) (side question, does anyone have insight why my [GitHub pages site](https://petervkay.github.io/roiCalculator/) gives a 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create a custom component to place inside of redux-form's `Field`, in which you hold an internal state, and sync this with the `formReducer` whenever you want.

You can achieve this in a couple of steps:

1. Create a custom component to use inside of `Field`. This component is injected [with a `meta` and `input` prop](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/field.md/#props).
2. Create your `state` for your React Component in which you will keep track of the data that you'll eventually emit to the formReducer.
3. In your constructor, use `props.input.value` to set your initial state. If you do this, you can use the 'initialValues' object for your `reduxForm`.
4. Use `connect` by `react-redux` to make it possible to use `react-form`'s action creators. In your case you'll be using the [`change` action creator](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/field.md/#props).
5. Create your render function with your input-field and fire the `change` action to modify your formReducer's value for this field.

So that comes down to something like this:

```
<Field
  name="daysPerWeek"
  component={MyCustomComponent} // 1
/>

...

class MyCustomComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: props.input.value, // 2 and 3
    }
  }

  ....
}
```

**4:**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { change } from 'react-form';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  ourCustomChange: (value) => dispatch(change(ownProps.meta.form, ownProps.input.name, value))
})

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(MyCustomComponent);
```

**5:**

```
....
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if (prevState.value !== this.state.value) {
     this.debounceAndEmit();
   }
 }

 debounceAndEmit() {
   // Debounce for some time. Maybe use:
   // import { debounce } from 'throttle-debounce';
   // for that:
   debounce(2000, () => {
     this.props.ourCustomChange(this.state.value)
   })
 }

 handleChange(event) {
   // Do things here like trimming the string, regex, whatever.
   this.setState({ value: event.target.value })
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        {...this.props.input} // Includes standard redux-form bindings for input fields. 
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
      />
    )
  }
....
```

In some cases you might have to use the [blur action creator](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/#-code-blur-form-string-field-string-value-any-code-) too. For when you're doing stuff when clicking outside of an input field for example.

If you want form fields to change depending on other fields, you should use [selectors](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/selectors.md/) to inject their values into your custom component to respond to that.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks so much Alserda, I'll start trying this out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: All of these tips were spot on.  I'm not quite done getting the functionality implemented, but have a lot of the needed infrastructure in place now. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterBreen Good to hear! If you still have any questions concering this - I’ll still be active heee.